# ARIMA Time series forecasting in R, help on choosing adequate model

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, model-selection

I am trying to create adequate time series model in R. I have doubt about adequacy. My data is year and total number of events:

`year<-c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015)
total<-c(14,14,28,15,26,17,19,11,14,20,25)`

Under is my R code for ARIMA

```
mt<-ts(total,start=2005)
ma<-Arima(mt,order=c(3,1,1),seasonal = c(3,1,0))

summary(ma)
forecast<-(ma)
plot(forecast(ma,5))
tsdisplay(residuals(ma))
```

If there is somebody who can help to find best model and explain how to do it.

Comment: You have yearly, i.e., non-seasonal data. Thus, the `seasonal` parameter to `Arima()` does not do anything.

Comment: I added the [tag:arima] and [tag:model-selection] tags to your question. I recommend that you browse through [previous questions carrying both tags](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-selection+arima?sort=votes&pageSize=50), you will get a better idea about how to select ARIMA models.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `forecast` package's `auto.arima()` function.

```
# install.packages("forecast")
library("forecast")

total <- c(14,14,28,15,26,17,19,11,14,20,25)

mt <- ts(total,start=2005)

model = auto.arima(mt)
```

This gives:

```
Series: mt 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept
        18.4545
s.e.     1.6332

sigma^2 estimated as 32.27:  log likelihood=-34.19
AIC=72.38   AICc=73.88   BIC=73.18
```

Note: The model returned is an `ARMA(0,0)` which is a white noise: `x_t = mu + ε_t`, where `ε_t ~ N(0, sig^2)`

You may want to disable the mean:

```
model = auto.arima(mt, allowmean=F)

plot(model)
```

This would give:

```
Series: mt 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean     

Coefficients:
         ar1
      0.9091
s.e.  0.0981

sigma^2 estimated as 74.24:  log likelihood=-39.65
AIC=83.3   AICc=84.8   BIC=84.1
```

with an AR1 root in:

[image: AR1_root]

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt reply. I have been trying different models and found that ARIMA (3,0,1) is graphically and using RMSE and R square best fit the data. Now I am trying to model the outlier (third case, 28). How to enroll this outlier in the equation. I have tried some models in SPSS but I would rather do it in R.

Comment: "Best fit" is not a good criterion for model choice. You can always improve the in-sample fit by expending additional degrees of freedom, but your out-of-sample forecast accuracy will degrade eventually, because of overfitting. An ARIMA(3,1,1) model has *four* parameters. This is *far* too complex if you have only eleven observations. I *strongly* suspect that the simpler model found by `auto.arima()` will yield better forecasts.